# AWS Data Pipeline - How to set global pipeline variable from ShellCommandActivity

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

I am trying to augment my pipeline (migrates data from RDS to RedShift) so that it selects all rows whose `id` is greater than the maximum `id` that exists in RedShift. I have a script in Python that calculates this value and returns it to the output. I want to take this output and save it to a variable `max_id` that I can later reference in my RDS selection query. For example, my RDS selection section currently looks like this:

```
{
  "database": {
    "ref": "rds_mysql"
  },
  "scheduleType": "TIMESERIES",
  "name": "SrcRDSTable",
  "id": "SrcRDSTable",
  "type": "SqlDataNode",
  "table": "#{myRDSTableName}",
  "selectQuery": "select * from #{table} where #{myRDSTableLastModifiedCol} > '#{max_id}'"
},
```

I then want to add a section before this that would execute the bash script, retrieve the `id` field and save it to the variable `max_id` so that it can be referenced in the above code. So far I have:

```
{
 "myComment": "Retrieves the maximum ID for a given table in RedShift",
  "id": "ShellCommandActivity_Max_ID",
  "workerGroup": "wg-12345",
  "type": "ShellCommandActivity",
  "command": "starting_point=$(/usr/bin/python /home/user/aws-taskrunner-docker/get_id.py --schema=schema_name --table=users --database=master)"
},
```

How can I adjust the above to set `max_id` to the value of `starting_point`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't think that there's a way to set a pipeline parameter during pipeline execution. Here are a couple options that may help you.

First, if your data table has a column for modification date, then you can use the pipeline template [Incremental Copy of RDS MySQL to Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-template-redshiftrdsincremental.html). If you're not using MySQL, you may still be able to modify that template to your needs.

Alternatively, instead of using the SqlDataNode, you could create a ShellCommandActivity that uses python to connect to your RDS database and exports the relevant record set to S3. You could then import the records from S3 using the RedshiftCopyActivity.